# Training or Protection?

Tags: dogs

**Critical ages for puppies**

So after reading many sites, it seems that at the 8-16 week period for a puppy, it is ideal to enroll them into training classes and socialize them, however; vaccination for Parvo starts at 8 weeks and isn't completed until they reach around  16 weeks.

**Question**

So I would think that most of the puppies enrolled would not have completed their vaccination period? Would it be better to enroll and have them socialize or to keep them safe and not risk Parvo?

Also FYI our puppy is 10 weeks old right now.

Comment: Related [Should a puppy with its first vaccinations meet a dog that’s not fully vaccinated?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/21992/13)

Comment: `Start by introducing your puppy to known ‘safe’ dogs – dogs that you know have a good temperament and that have been fully vaccinated. It’s best to do this in a safe environment such as your backyard. You can also try socialising your puppy by introducing them to lots of different people and by giving puppy school a whirl.` Would a safe dog be puppies in the class then? @JamesJenkins

Answer (score 2):

https://www.reddit.com/r/dogs/comments/5izmh2/help_how_do_i_socialize_an_unvaccinated_puppy/

According to a decent number of Reddit posters:

- There are special puppy classes for those who have had the first round of vaccines.
- These puppies would be deemed safe as they are not showing Parvo symptoms (lethargic, diarrhea, etc)

Also there are classes for next round of shots, and so forth. We will be looking for local classes that meet the above requirement.